# How to list both files and folders based on time of creation on python?

Tags: python, timestamp, listdir

I am a newbie to python and linux. I want a solution for listing the files and folders based on the timestamp. I know this is already asked. But I cannot get an insight in what I am doing. I want the code to return the latest created file or folder. I have a script that identifies the type of content(file or folder). I need it to get the latest created content. The content identifier goes like this.

```
import os
dirlist=[]
dirlist2=[]
for filename in os.listdir('/var/www/html/secure_downloads'):
    if (os.path.isdir(os.path.join('/var/www/html/secure_downloads',filename))):
        dirlist.append(filename)
    else:
       dirlist2.append(filename)
print "For Folders",dirlist 
print "For Files",dirlist2
```

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1: Use `glob`

I found this great article here: https://janakiev.com/blog/python-filesystem-analysis/

### Option 2: Pipe the output of `ls -l` to python

The way I initially thought about solving this issue is doing the following...

You can list all the directories and their timestamps with `ls -l`.

Then you can pipe that output using subprocess like this:

```
import subprocess
proc=subprocess.Popen('echo "to stdout"', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
output=proc.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

Comment: I mean, I can't understand the option 2. Could you explain step by step. Sorry I am total noob.